# Why would a displacement with a periodic image not tile smoothly?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am using a periodic image of noise (1/f noise) to displace a plane, with the displace modifier, into a random lumpy shape. When I connect 2 surfaces the seam is clearly visible and I don't know why. The image is definitely periodic, and if I don't use UV space the texture tiles seamlessly in the middle of the surface, but always shows at the seam of 2 pieces

[image]

Any way to get rid of this so I can tile several planes seamlessly?

[image: The seam is in the middle of the image]

Comment: In the image mapping try to change the extension to one of the available options.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate vertexes? Edit Mode > A (Select All) > Remove doubles

Comment: could you share the texture jpg?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the smoothing function. As one surface get's near one edge, it doesn't know how the curvature will continue on the other side and the smoothing function sets it as if the object ends there, using no interpolation between the disconnected edges. This happens from both sides of the common edge, and therefore it's quite noticeable.

To correct this, one must edit the vertex normals from each side, to include the derivation from one surface's normal to the other.
However this might be very tedious to do by hand, so I advise a good normal editor addon. For example, [Y.A.V.N.E.](https://github.com/fedackb/yavne) has one function for this (the [merge](https://github.com/fedackb/yavne#merge) normals), and all one need is to join the meshes (if in different objects), select the edge vertices, merge the normals and separate the meshes again (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Your texture could have a tiny little border of 1 pixel on its edges. Edit it in Gimp or Photoshop - Zoom to see if there's a border and crop if necessary.